# Не получается задеплоить telegram bot (на python) на heroku

Tags: python, telegram-bot, heroku

Здравствуйте.
Написал бота для телеграм на python. Пытаюсь загрузить на хероку.
Я сделал репу, добавил requirements.txt (как говориться в инструкции)

```
pytelegrambotapi
```

далее Procfile

```
bot: python main.py
```

и runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.0
```

Задеплоил это всё с github. Активировал, но бот не работает. 
Application error

В чём могут быть проблемы? Когда запускаю локально всё работает.

Comment: В чём угодно. Смотрите в логи. Вы же их ведёте?

Comment: Вы про логи которые ведутся на heroku при сборке или я чего то не знаю?

Comment: Нет, что в рантайме должны выводиться в stdout. Доступны по команде `heroku logs`.

Comment: Да кажется нашёл:
2017-03-16T13:25:29.368373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/b8f49db7-eca4-46af-9dfc-d31d1c40e8b2" host=twiggbot.herokuapp.com request_id=5ce42877-bec7-47f9-8027-c144f2677e9d fwd="149.154.167.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Код ошибки H14